# Issues with Push Notification

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, push-notification, parse-platform

I am experiencing an issue with Parse Push notification, where I am trying to implement user to user push notification, and in the back end it does show that the message have been sent, however, in reality the message is not being displayed to the user.

Also, it seems that the message is sent to all of the user in the query, where it should only be sent to the user matched.

Below is the portion of the code that deals with Push Notification

```
 query1.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects,ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {

            for(int i=0;i<objects.size();i++){
                // Do whatever you need to extract object from "users"
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query1 = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
                query1.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                        .getObjectId());

                query1.setLimit(1);

                query1.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("UserAge", minimumAge);
                query1.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("UserAge", maximumAge);

                Button buttonconfirm = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnMatchConfirm);
                buttonconfirm.setText("Confirm");

                mUserNameRetrieved = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistname);

                mUserNameRetrieved.setText(objects.get(i).get("Name").toString()); 


                Button newPage = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.btnMatchConfirm);

              newPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                  //    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

                //      currentUser.put("UserMatchName", mUserRetrieved);
                      Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), matchOptionActivity.class);
                      startActivity(intent);

                      sendPushNotifications();

                  }

                private void sendPushNotifications() {
                    ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();


                    //send push notification
                    ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
                push.setQuery(query);
                push.setMessage(getActivity()
                        .getString(R.string.push_match_request_message, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId()));
                push.sendInBackground();

                }
              });

           }
         } else if (e != null) {




           }
       }
   });
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable option on parse.com

Go to settings on parse.com == > push == > "Client Push enabled" Yes.